# Lost with fragments activity

Tags: android

currently I'm studying about the fragments activity for showing a dialog but I really can't get it why I can't show my dialog. so here's the sample I use from android developers page:

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

and used this for calling the dialog:

```
public void confirmFireMissiles() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new mainActivity();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");
}
```

Now the getSupportFragmentManager always turns red and when I focus on it it gives me an error saying Cannot resolve method 'show(?,java.lang.String)' and Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'. I'm now on a panic mode and I don't know what to do with this. I already imported what's needed but I don't know why does this still happens.

Comment: Are you calling `confirmFireMissiles()` in the FragmentActivity ?

Comment: I'm calling that in my mainActivity onCreate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below.

Say on Button click.

```
   DialogFragment newFragment = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
   newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "missiles");
```

Edit:

import the below if your min sdk is below api 11. extend FragmentActivity

```
  import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

use

```
  DialogFragment newFragment = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
  newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");
```

Comment: Still gives me this:
Cannot resolve method 'show(android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)' Anyway I'm using android studio for this that's what it says when I hover on the getFragmentManager() part. I'm really lost with using this fragments.

Comment: I also wonder why it's not working on my case. been nuts for hours because of this.

Comment: oh I get it, it's because I'm using a v4 support import for this. tried using the default imports and it works. but I wonder if it will also work for android version 2.2 and up? Any workarounds I can do for this?

Comment: check the note part in the link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: If your app's minSdkVersion is 11 or higher, you can instead use the platform version of DialogFragment.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: check the edit in the answer. that should work if your min sdk is below 11

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31570/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-kahel)